# No design-time type metadata found error with Loopback

Tags: typescript, loopback4

I have the following 500 error when executing a controller with Loopback 4.

```
Unhandled error in GET /v1/me/societes: 500 Error: No design-time type metadata found while inspecting FirebaseAuthService.constructor[2]. You can either use `@service(ServiceClass)` or ensure `emitDecoratorMetadata` is enabled in your TypeScript configuration. Run `tsc --showConfig` to print the final TypeScript configuration of your project.
```

I think the problem is because of `FirebaseService` injection here :

```
@injectable({scope: BindingScope.SINGLETON})
export class FirebaseAuthService {
  constructor(
    @repository(UtilisateurRepository)
    public utilisateurRepository: UtilisateurRepository,
    @repository(TokenRepository)
    public tokenRepository: TokenRepository,
    @service(FirebaseService)
    public firebaseService: FirebaseService,
  ) {}
```

But the `FirebaseService` class looks OK :

```
@injectable({scope: BindingScope.SINGLETON})
export class FirebaseService {
```

All my service classes are in `src/services` directory, so they should be registered by Loopback. Or maybe my problem has nothing to deal with service injections ?

I try to understand this for hours. Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks for your help !

Olivier

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem. You need to import the full path to this file instead of folder.
EX: import ServiceA from './services/service-a.service';

Comment: Anybody know how this solves the issue? I'm guessing that resolving the class metadata uses the imported path as a key somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by removing circular dependency in service injections